# Nginx permissions

Tags: django, nginx, static

I deployed the server with Ubuntu 18, Django, Gunicorn, Nginx
And I ran into this problem:

everything works great **but**,
When I upload large pictures files in Django, Nginx gives **403 Error Forbidden**.

I updated the permissions to the folder with static files on 755. It works!
**But** when I upload other files, the rights do not work.

I added the user root and user www-data to the folder owner’s group, but nothing has changed.

I understand that Nginx has no permissions, but how can I implement the inheritance permissions of new files from the parent folder

**or will you suggest another solution?**

Comment: have you given permission to media folder

Comment: yes, recursively

Comment: try adding this to your settings.py file- `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644`

Comment: god damn, yeah! thank you very much!!!!
Can you explain where I can see the full list of permissions?

Comment: @CoderBug Please check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions. Also sorry for late response, I was travelling :D. I will post this as a answer, Please accept it if this was useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS=0o644` variable to you `settings.py` file.
This is the numeric mode (i.e. 0o644) to newly uploaded files to.

For more information, please read this [doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions)

Answer (score -1):

Try use this

```
chown -R www-data:www-data 'your project folder'
```

Comment: NOT! This takes away rights from the main owner, I have already done a similar - I added the user root and user www-data to the folder owner’s group, but nothing has changed.

Comment: This is wrong approach.